# Azure b2c - Msal js - SPA - Edit profile

Tags: azure-active-directory

Did anyone try 'profile edit' with MSAL with spa? If so can you please point me to some demo samples? Thanks in advance.

I was able to integrate 'SignIn', 'SignUp' and 'PasswordReset' but when integrating profile edit it did the route to 'profile edit' policy but the issue is, the application is asking to sign in again to edit the user profile.

Below is the code,

```
 private clientApplication: Msal.UserAgentApplication;

  constructor(private router: Router, private token: tokenDataService) {

    this.clientApplication =
      new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
        environment.clientID,
        this.authority,
        this.authCallback.bind(this),
        {
          redirectUri: window.location.origin
        });
  }

  public login(): void {
    this.clientApplication.loginRedirect(environment.b2cScopes);
  }

  public editProfile() {
    let clientApp = window.msal as Msal.UserAgentApplication;
    clientApp.authority = this.profileEditAuthority;
    clientApp.loginRedirect(environment.b2cScopes);
  }

  public logout(): void {
    this.clientApplication.logout();
  }
  public firstLogin(): string {
    return this.clientApplication.getUser().idToken['newUser'];
  }
  public isOnline(): boolean {
    return this.clientApplication.getUser() != null;

  }

  public getUser(): User {

    return this.clientApplication.getUser();
  }

  public getAuthenticationToken(): Promise<string> {

    return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(environment.b2cScopes)
      .then(token => {
        this.token.set(token);
        console.log('hi')
        console.log(token);

        return token;
      }).catch(error => {
        return this.clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(environment.b2cScopes)
          .then(token => {
            return Promise.resolve(token);
          }).catch(innererror => {
            console.error('Could not retrieve token from popup.', innererror);
            return Promise.resolve('');
          });
      });
  }

  private authCallback(errorDesc: any, token: any, error: any, tokenType: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['/pages/home']);

    if (error) {
      if (errorDesc.indexOf("AADB2C90118") > -1) {

        let clientApp = window.msal as Msal.UserAgentApplication;
        clientApp.authority = this.resetpasswordAuthority;

        clientApp.loginRedirect(environment.b2cScopes);
      }
      console.error(`${error} ${errorDesc}`);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This tutorial has it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-spa

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue?